# MySQL: extremely inconsistent Rows_examined number between similar queries

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a fairly complex query that we have optimized very carefully. It works well, except that from time to time, it suddenly takes much more time than usual. It does not seem to be CPU or RAM related.

We have been able to isolate what seems to be the problem: the slow instances of the query show a very high Rows_examined number in slow_query.log:

```
 - Normal execution time: Rows_examined: 140003
 - Slow execution time: Rows_examined: 2265473
```

Yet, the query is pretty much always the same: we only adjust a condition slightly and the variation can't explain such a change in number of rows (we checked manually). Besides:

```
 - the slowness occurs fairly randomly.
 - when we "explain" the queries, the output is exactly the same
```

**The query looks like this:**

```
SELECT A2.stuff, B.stuff, C.stuff FROM
    (SELECT A.stuff WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...) A2
STRAIGHT_JOIN B
STRAIGHT_JOIN C
WHERE ...
```

I apologise: it is a fairly open question. I am just hoping someone knows about this behaviour and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Almost sounds like the optimiser is barfing.

Comment: Does the slow version have the same query plan as the normal one?

Comment: @Vatev Yes, exactly the same query plan. The two queries only differ by a slight condition change.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is there a method to validate this hypothesis?

Comment: have you tried to move ORDER BY and LIMIT to the outer-most query to give the optimizer a better chance to avoid creating temporary tables, especially if you join on indexed columns..?

Comment: @deathApril Thanks. I should have added a comment here: I tried A LOT of things without any successes. I ended up updating mySQL to 5.6 (our stack was on 5.0) and the problem seems to be gone.

Comment: solved by upgrading to newer version of MySQL => should we close this question or do you want to answer your own question?